# Determine If This Is A Symbolic Link

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage, symbolic-link

I'm in the process of getting a second server connected to a Dell MD3000i.  I'm trying to do it the exact same way the server before it was setup.  It has a folder in the C Drive that goes virtual volume on the SAN.  I believe this is a Symbolic Link, since that is the only thing I have been able to come up with in my research.  How can I know for sure if that is what it is, and see what the details are for the link so I can create the same thing on the second server?

I'm not sure if the picture below will help much, but I will post it anyways.  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within `cmd.exe`, the command `DIR C:\ /A` should give you details about the directory.  Below is a snip of my example output:

```
C:\>DIR C:\ /A
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 84AB-3C28

 Directory of C:\

09/10/2012  01:25 PM    <DIR>          $Recycle.Bin
07/19/2012  01:44 PM    <DIR>          Boot
11/20/2010  10:23 PM           383,786 bootmgr
07/19/2012  01:44 PM             8,192 BOOTSECT.BAK
01/11/2013  10:33 AM    <SYMLINKD>     TestSymLink [C:\Some\Other\Path]
01/11/2013  10:29 AM    <DIR>          Config.Msi
07/14/2009  12:08 AM    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
11/01/2012  07:50 AM    <DIR>          DRIVERS
09/17/2012  02:34 PM    <DIR>          metasploit
07/19/2012  10:35 AM    <DIR>          MSOCache
<snip>
11/29/2012  03:00 PM    <DIR>          Windows
               3 File(s)  4,184,565,638 bytes
              16 Dir(s)  59,202,383,872 bytes free
```

The third column indicates the type.  Both Junctions and Symlinks will indicate their targets within the square brackets to the right of the Junction/Link name.

- `<DIR>` = Directory
- `<SYMLINKD>` = Symbolic Link
- `<JUNCTION>` = Juntion Point
- No Type = File

Comment: I guess this isn't a Symbolic Link.  It shows as <DIR> all the way down the folder path.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\ClusterStorage` is an abstraction providing access to Cluster Shared Volumes from all members of a Hyper-V cluster. It's created and managed by the Cluster Service.

What you need to do is:

- Make sure that the SAN volumes connected to server A are also connected to server B.
- Install the Hyper-V role and the Failover Clustering feature on server B.
- Validate the configuration of server B. Fix all errors/warnings before proceeding.
- Add server B to the cluster.

After integrating server B into the cluster the folder is automatically created and populated.

Comment: From what I've been told clustering was never completely setup.  They made an attempt at it 2 years ago, but something failed along the way.  I guess this is left over from that, and wont be able to set it up the same way on the second server.

Comment: Without a cluster you don't have the functionality that `C:\ClusterStorage` is supposed to provide. More specifically, do **not** access the same SAN volume from different servers **unless** the volumes are configured as cluster shared volumes. You will destroy your data otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I learned that the other day after a couple hours on the phone with Dell.  So I got new drives, installed them last night, and created a new virtual volume to work with.  I just didn't know that this was left over from that failed project.  I really hope that this server can be decommissioned soon, since hyper v is getting me cluster errors as well.